# What is the compatible jooq version for postgressql 12.7 and java 8?

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have used jooq 3.11.9 for postgressql 9.4.1210 with java 8. java version remain the same. want to change the postgressql version to 12.7. What is the most ideal jooq version?

Comment: `9.4.1210` looks like the version of the JDBC driver, not a "Postgres" version. Are you referring to the JDBC driver version or really the Postgres (server) version?

Answer (score 1):

The latest open source version that supports Java 8 is 3.14.15.

You should consider to update to Java 11+

Answer (score 0):

You can find this information on the [jOOQ RDBMS support matrix page](https://www.jooq.org/download/support-matrix). Regarding your specific version requirements:

- The commercial editions of jOOQ versions 3.14+ support PostgreSQL 12+ and more.
- The jOOQ Open Source Edition 3.14 supports PostgreSQL 12
- The jOOQ Open Source Edition 3.15 supports PostgreSQL 13
- The jOOQ Open Source Edition 3.16 supports PostgreSQL 14